# Hide Data labels that are long in piechart drilldown

Tags: highcharts, pie-chart, drilldown

In the drilldown part of the pie chart I have a few big labels ,which are going beyond the div and not visible. I want to show datalabels ending with.

For Example:

```
helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo
```

[image: Image 1]

This is my Output

```
hellooooo...
```

[image: Image 2]

Expected output with no change in size, size must be as in pic 1 data labels as in pic 2

Comment: it is hard to answer this post. see here [how it works](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: i have made changes to the quesion see if you can help...

Comment: i couldn't reproduce your issue, the default behaviour is to add the elipsis overflow, could you edit this fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net/de5uqaav/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/de5uqaav/1/  I have updated the fiddle.  I have explicitly mentioned the size as 120 so the default ellipsis is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Solved [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41891276/3898339) question before.

Asuming words cannot be like *helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo* .It has to be different group of words

Add [plotOptions](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.pie) in chart as

```
   plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            style: {
                width: '100px'
            },
            enabled: true,
            color: '#000000',
            maxStaggerLines:1,                    
            connectorColor: '#000000',
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'                   

        },
    }
},
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/howan4b2/)

Before Drill
[image: Before Drill]

After Drill

[image]

**Note** If you want to use *helloooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo* and have ellipse.

Then See this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/63ymx980/)

Add Css

```
#container {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
```

[image: ellipse]